# Meaning of mkdir parameters in Android init.rc

Tags: linux, ubuntu, unix, permissions, android-source

I am trying to understand the following commands:

1. mkdir /data 0770 root system
2. mkdir /data 0770 system system
3. mkdir /data 0770 system room

https://android.googlesource.com/platform/system/core/+/b4d65399fde02280b718e3b5b5cb1464a885c4b0/rootdir/init.rc
Line 58

mkdir is creating the directory,
/data is path,
0770 giving read write permissions to the directory,
root system I don't know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The format is

```
mkdir <path> [mode] [user] [group]
```

The path defines which directory has to be created. The mode defines the permissions for the directory. The user and group define who is the owner of the directory. The permissions are relative to the user and the group owning the directory. For example, `mkdir /data 0770 root system` means the `/data` directory is owned by the user `root` and the group `system`. The `root` user has read/write/execute permissions (because of the first `7`) and the same holds for every user that is a member of the `system` group (because of the second `7`). Every other user has no permissions (because of the last `0`). The leading `0` has no special meaning in this case, it just signifies the beginning of an octal number.

The commands that can be used in the `init.rc` are defined [here](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/system/core/+/4f23d5a236e08ed2d9413cf2681f8ed967d01deb/init/builtins.cpp).

You can also inspect the user and group that owns a directory from the command line, using `ls -l`:

```
# ls -l
...
drwxrwx---  45 root system     920 1971-02-01 00:26 data
```

Since you mentioned security labels: These permissions are unrelated to SE Linux labels. The file permissions are considered Discretionary Access Control ([DAC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discretionary_access_control)), whereas SE Linux labels are Mandatory Access Control ([MAC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mandatory_access_control)).

You can inspect the SE Linux label with `ls -lZ`:

```
# ls -lZ                                                                                                                                       
...
drwxrwx--x  45 root system u:object_r:system_data_file:s0 920 1971-02-01 00:26 data
```

So in this case the SE Linux label would be `u:object_r:system_data_file:s0`. In general, the SE Linux label of a file would not be set dynamically via the `init.rc`. Rather, the labels are defined statically via the `file_contexts` file in the SE Linux policy ([reference](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/system/sepolicy/+/master/private/file_contexts#493)). Newly created files by default inherit the SE Linux label of their parent directory. To apply the label from the policy to a newly created file, the `restorecon` command can be used, as can be seen e.g. [here](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/system/core/+/43dca3c8be0c35781e5c691988ae6c2a317311ba/rootdir/init.rc#554).